# c++ when copying inner function pointer to object to function passed pointer the value don't change

Tags: c++, pointers

i want to change the pointer to where it point to with out success 
here is what i have :

```
class Test {
public:
    Test() {};
    ~Test(){};
    int foo;
};
void ToPointer(Test *tst)
{
    Test* t1 = new Test();
    t1->foo = 111222;
    tst = t1;
}

Test *t2 = new Test();
t2->foo = 2;
ToPointer(t2);
int fff = t2->foo;
```

The result of fff is still 2
i want t2 to point to t1 or at list copy all its values
here i just simplify it with foo but in real life the object is much more complex
i dont what to use reference to pointer ( * &)

Comment: Either you use a reference or you do `*tst = t1`. Find what's the difference in your C++ book.

Comment: Also, 9k+ of reputation and no mvce in your question. You should know how SO works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since pointers are passed by value, and you don't wish to use reference-to-pointer, you could use pointer-to-pointer like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    Test() {};
    ~Test(){};
    int foo;
};

// tst will be a pointer to the pointer (address) of the Test instance.
void ToPointer(Test** tst)
{
    Test* t1 = new Test();
    t1->foo = 111222;
    *tst = t1;  // you can use the pointer tst, 
                // even though it is a copy of the original argument,
                // because it points to the pointer that points to the Test instance.
}

int main()
{
    Test* t2 = new Test();  // t2 stores the address of the Test instance
    t2->foo = 2;
    ToPointer(&t2);         // send ToPointer() the address of t2, 
                            // which is itself a pointer to the Test instance
    int fff = t2->foo;
    cout << fff << endl;    // verify that fff is 111222

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass t2 to ToPointer(Test* tst) what's happening is ToPointer() is making a local copy of that pointer. Then you assign tst to t1, but all that's doing is assigning that local copy. The one back in main will still be sitting there untouched. And the local copy in ToPointer will die when the function returns. There are many things you can do, like take the pointer as a pointer to pointer Test**, or a reference to pointer Test*&, or like user64322 said, return a pointer, or return a reference to a reference to a pointed to pointer, the choices are limitless.

Answer (score 1):

The porblem with your code is

Let say T2 is pointer at

```
0x1000
```

pointing to 0X2000
and tsk is pointer at

```
0x1010 also pointing to 0x2000
```

now t1 pointer is at

```
0x3000
```

and pointong at lets say

```
0x4000
```

now you have done tsk = t1

means tsk will point to 0x4000

and remember, t2 is still at 0x1000 ans pointing to 0x2000

One of the solution will be
 to return t1

```
Test *ToPointer()
{
    Test* t1 = new Test();
    t1->foo = 111222;
    return t1;
}
int main()
{
    Test *t2 = new Test();
    t2->foo = 2;
    t2 = ToPointer();
    int fff = t2->foo;
    std::cout<<fff;
}
```